# Is this lecture recorded or is this lecture being recorded?

Tags: difference, tense

During a zoom class one of my classmates asked the lecturer:

> Is this lecture recorded?

I am wondering is this question grammatically correct?

or

> Is this lecture being recorded?

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, but implies that the lecture being referred to has completed. The second sentence would be grammatically correct and imply that the lecture is in progress.

People do use the first form and leave out the words that help understand whether the lecture is in progress, almost like being recorded is an attribute of a lecture whether ongoing or not.